# Define new css class and access its members in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am defining a css class, and trying to use its member from javascript. The result is undefined. Where is my mistake?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myId").style.myMember;
  document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
.myClass {
  myMember: 123;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to get the style property of the myId element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="debug"></p>

<div id="myId" class="myClass">
  My content.
</div>
```

The [example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPDQGK3PR27M) at w3schools, if you want to try it.

---

Some background: I'm trying to create a very simple page with slideshow. I found out a way to create the slides in css thanks to w3schools (sorry, it's what comes out on top when I search).

Now I want to be able to set the display time separately for each slide in the html file, and this time to have a default value if it's omitted.

It seemed reasonable for display time to be part of the style of the slide, at least logical in my head. I understand now from the answers so far that the css styles can't be added to with custom attributes, is that correct?

What would be the correct way to pass a display time from this:

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="img.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

to this javascript function?:

```
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 500); // Get display time from html instead!
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't refer to w3schools - loads of bad practices.. like this one xD

Comment: Are you confusing CSS classes and JS classes? CSS should only be used for styling really.

Comment: Its pretty unclear what you're trying to do, and why, can you elaborate?

Comment: No, if you run the example on w3c and click on the button, you'll also get undefined! Use CSS only for styling, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Gauthier I'm guessing this is the sort of thing you were expecting https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/x1s83qsg/ I see you have a background in some other Object Orientated languages and how that could make the word classes confusing.

Comment: As you can see, I'm a total noob (I come from embedded). I'll take w3schools with a pinch of salt in the future.

Comment: @AndrewBone: right, but I'd like to set the value of myMember in the html, see my edit for some background.

Comment: @Gauthier I think you're probably looking for this then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: @AndrewBone Nice, going with `data-*`, and checking if not defined in the js, setting default there. Good enough for now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `element.style` object will give you the style values which is defined inline in that particular element...

Second `myMember` is not an valid css property so it will give you nothing...

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myId").style.display;
  document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to get the style property of the myId element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="debug"></p>

<div id="myId" style="display:block">
  My content.
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, so css styles are not expandable?

Comment: @Gauthier no they are not...however you can explore css variables if they fit in your requirement...[**Read this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)

Answer (score 0):

if you enter in the console "document.getElementById("myId").style", you get all the applicable styles to your given selection. the class "my123" is not recognised in there that's why you get the result as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to declare "myMember" as property and want to use it in Javascript but myMember is not a CSS property so its returning undefined.

The style property returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object, which represents an element's style attribute.

The style property is used to get or set a specific style of an element using different CSS properties.